# How can I add a button after each list item in a Jade loop?

Tags: html, node.js, pug, template-engine

Can't seem to find an answer for this anywhere. Maybe I don't know how to search for it correctly.

I currently have:

```
each val in district_list
  li= val
  button.btn.btn-sm(type="submit") Remove
```

This adds a Remove button just under each list item. But I want to have it on the same line as the list text. Something like:

```
each val in district_list
  li= val button.btn.btn-sm(type="submit") Remove
```

but without treating everything after `val` as plain text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
each val in district_list
  li
    = val
    button.btn.btn-sm(type="submit") Remove
```